# JavaFX application won't start when running JNLP form website

Tags: javafx, jnlp, java-web-start

I have created a JavaFX 2.2 application that I am trying to deploy using web start. I singed the application with a proper certificate (not self-signed) which I actually use for another Swing application for another client of mine. I used this certificate because I still don't have the new one for this client and I wanted to test the process.

I use Netbeans 7.3, JDK 7_21 and JRE 7 _21. I pack the application using Netbeans with all the necessary settings for a web start application. I can run my application locally on my and others PCs and its working fine.

The problem starts when I upload the application on the clients website. Website link works fine, JNLP is downloaded fine but when I run it I get a Runtime error. Click here for details but there are no actual details in the console. Any ideas would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind whoever took the time to read my question. I wasn't including the codebase setting in my jnlp. Added and working fine.

Thanks for your time

Comment: *"I wasn't including the codebase"*  Be sure to check JNLP files using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip I will defenately have a look